# Extracting only the common substrings from two string columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract every substring that two string separated by comma columns have and store the common values into a 3rd column (again by comma separated) if no common values then return 'NA'.
I've been scouring the internet with no luck. I tried multiple solutions that I was able to find.

The most recent try that I gave it was this one:

```
df1['Col_C'] = df1[df1[['Col_A', 'Col_B']].apply(lambda x : x[0]==x[1],axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True).copy()

Input:

Index         Col_A                    Col_B
  0    James,Harrison,Maria   Maria,Harrison,Peter,John
  1         Jim,Maria             Jimmy,Michael
  
Desired Output:

Index          Col_A                    Col_B                  Col_C
  0    James,Harrison,Maria    Maria,Harrison,Peter,John   Maria,Harrison
  1          Jim,Maria             Jimmy,Michael                 NA
```

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the order of output matter? Maria,Harrison,James is acceptable?

Comment: No it doesn't, I should have clarified that.

Comment: Can you check your output please? Some names appear, some disappear.

Comment: @Corralien let me know if now it's more clear.

Comment: It's clear now but you also removed all duplicates from `Col_A` and `Col_B`?

Comment: Yeah I did it only for simplicity. I am only interested in keeping just one of each value in common. No matter the amount of times they appear in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your values into `list` and convert them as a `set`. So you can use `intersection` predicate to find common names between 2 columns:

```
intersect = lambda x: set(x['Col_A'].split(',')).intersection(x['Col_B'].split(','))
df['Col_C'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(intersect(x)), axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
                  Col_A                      Col_B           Col_C
0  James,Harrison,Maria  Maria,Harrison,Peter,John  Maria,Harrison
1             Jim,Maria              Jimmy,Michael
```